# How to solve this sum of fractions in terms of $k$?

Tags: summation

I'm interested in solving the series
$$\frac{2}{1\cdot3}+\frac{3}{3\cdot5}+\frac{4}{5\cdot7}\cdots+\frac{n+1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}.$$

That is, $$\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k+1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}.$$

Can we get a concise representation for this summation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

Partial fraction expansion

$\frac{3}{4(2k-1)} - \frac {1}{4(2k+1)}$

Comment: Wow. That works! Thaks.

Comment: @h-squared very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fraction decomposition$$S_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{k+1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac34\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{ (2 k-1)}-\frac14\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{ (2 k+1)}$$
$$S_n=\frac{1}{4}H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{ n (1+2\log (2))+\log (2)}{(2 n+1)}$$

If $n$ is large, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\frac{1}{4} \left(\gamma +1+2\log
   (2)\right)+\frac{1}{4}\log(n)-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{7}{96 n^2}-\frac{1}{32
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Try for $n=10$; the exact value is
$$S_{10}=\frac{18983113}{14549535}\approx 1.3047230$$ while the above truncated expansion would give                               $1.3047217$.